# Include dependency information in gerrit REST api?

Tags: gerrit

The command line tool for gerrit has a --dependencies parameter for the query command. I cannot find the equivalent option for the REST api.

Instead, it appears I need to construct this information by running "submitted-together" for each change. That seems expensive.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you need to query out each change independently